# Mock only one function from module jest

Tags: jestjs

// utils.ts

```
export const foo = () => {...}
export const bar = () => {...}
```

I only want to mock foo function, bar must stay the same

```
jest.mock('../utils', () => {
    return {foo: jest.fn()}
})
```

Since I use Typescript, I cannot do like

```
import * as utils from '../utils'
utils.foo = jest.fn(() => console.log(..)) // Cannot assign read only
```

I can mock foo like this but I think bar function will be mocked as well. Could you show me the way to mock only foo function

Answer (score 1):

I do like this and it works. I'm not sure if it's the correct way to do it

```
jest.mock('../utils', () => {
    const utils = jest.requireActual('../utils')
    return {
        ...utils,
        foo: jest.fn(() => (...)),
    }
})
```